# input data for training USAD network

Tags: unsupervised-learning

During reading 'USAD: UnSupervised Anomaly Detection on Multivariate Time Series' paper, to train the autoencoder the authors only used normal datasets. But since this algorithm
is used for unsupervised learning, isn't there a chance that a dataset has no label. And if this True, are there solutions to solve this problem?